# Как сверстать заголовок уходящий влево?

Tags: css, html5, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Комментарий http://joxi.ru/12MQgX0SYb3P2J

И второй вопрос в догонку http://joxi.ru/EA4pdE5UzyPPAb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу заголовка просто сделайте сайдбар справа, а заголовок на всю ширину. Как? да как угодно:  `float: right;` через flexbox, `padding-left` для сайдбара и т.д.

Для нумерованного списка чтобы начать с 21 через атрибут `start`:

```
<ol start="21">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

выведется как

21. Coffee
22. Tea
23. Milk

Comment: Сейчас осенило по поводу заголовка, спасибо большое. Но вот со списком не решится задача, там же не 21, а 2.1 вот в чем дело... скриптами наверное придется или ручками?

Comment: Не разглядел сперва, сейчас помогу.

Comment: @alex-lenk, с помощью CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/p2vhr9qt/

Comment: Вы просто виртуоз! Спасибо большое!

Comment: @check1st Опередели меня:)